# CS0246 The type or namespace name 'MailKit' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, mailkit

I'm stuck with basic Mailkit implementation in ASP.NET Core, my error:

CS0246 The type or namespace name 'MailKit' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

```
using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient()) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install MailKit:

```
dotnet add package MailKit
```